# How to make my Queue class memory-leak proof in Typescript

Tags: typescript, memory, memory-leaks, queue

I have a class called Queue

```
export class Queue<T> {
    constructor(
        onNextItem: (data: T) => Promise<any>,
        onError: (error: Error) => void,
    ) {
        this.onNextItem = onNextItem
        this.onError = onError
    }

    private onNextItem: (data: T) => Promise<any>
    private onError: (error: Error) => void
    private rawData: T[] = []
    private isWorking = false

    addToQueue(request: T) {
        this.rawData.push(request)

        if (!this.isWorking) this.initiateHandling()
    }

    getLength(): number {
        return this.rawData.length
    }

    private initiateHandling() {
        if (this.rawData.length === 0) {
            this.isWorking = false
            return
        }
        this.isWorking = true

        const nextRequest = this.rawData.shift()

        this.onNextItem(nextRequest)
            .then(() => {
                this.initiateHandling()
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.onError(err)
            })
    }
}
```

One thing I am worried about is the `this.rawData` array. Even though I am popping array. I am afraid that it will at some point lead to a memory leak. Let's say the `onNextItem()` takes very little time and the array is mostly empty since there are only short burts of `addToQueue()`.

Are my worries justified?

I am running this code in a docker container and the docker container ran into a 137 error code which means that the container took more memory that it has available, that has caught my attention.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely room for a memory leak here. Consider the case where an execution of the `onNextItem` handler fails: your `isWorking` flag remains in `true` state, and your `initiateHandling()` function is never called again, causing the array to continue growing.

It's pretty easy to reproduce:

```
const q = new Queue<number>((n) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (n === -1) throw new Error();
    else resolve(n);
}), console.error);

q.addToQueue(-1);
q.addToQueue(0);
q.addToQueue(1);
q.addToQueue(2);
console.log(q.getLength());
```

Even more insidious would be the case in which one of your promises never resolves, or takes very long to resolve:

```
const q = new Queue<number>((n) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (n === -1) setTimeout(() => resolve(n), 60 * 1000);
    else resolve(n);
}), console.error);

q.addToQueue(-1);
q.addToQueue(0);
q.addToQueue(1);
q.addToQueue(2);
console.log(q.getLength()); // 3
```

You wouldn't even get an error message in this case.